# Activator bundle throwing null pointer exception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am facing a unique problem - the following code block throws NPE only when my plugin is packaged and deployed not when I am launching it as an 'Eclipse Application'

```
inputStream = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry(templateFilePath).openStream();
```

I have tried other variations as well but nothing is working :

```
inputStream=Platform.getBundle("SuitACore").getEntry(templateFilePath).openStream();
```

Here templateFilePath is a file resource being read from a directory in plugin.

Comment: What path are you using? Also are you certain the file is in the packaged jar? (when running from eclipse it runs from the expanded folder, not from the jar)

Comment: Make sure that the all the files you want to use in your plugin are listed in the build.properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nick , greg-449

I extracted the packaged jar - the template folder resource was not getting included. I changed this option from build.properties and now this works!